# What kind of pie is this?

Tags: pie

So over the thanks giving holiday my wife asked me to go get the apple pie out of the chill chest.  However there were three different pies in there and they all looked alike, and neither of us knew which was which.  We ended up cutting all of them to find the right pie, and made the blueberry pie we took to my parents house look really bad. I was wondering how can I determine what type of pie is in the refrigerator without breaking the structural integrity of the crust? Because I'm sure I'll do it again in the future.

Comment: Do you not have even tiny holes for ventilation you could sample through? And do you regard a toothpick hole as looking really bad?

Answer (score 15):

If you do this often I would make a little pastry cut out of the fruit type of the pie and use some egg wash to stick it onto the pie - it looks good and eases identification.

Comment: Anyone who bakes pies regularly should get in to this habit, edible labels make sense, pretty too.

Answer (score 13):

Label them before you put them away.

Use pictures of the filling in pastry on the top crust.

X-Ray machine?

Comment: How would you be able to identify the pies with an X-Ray machine? Would this defrost the pie?

Answer (score 7):

If you properly vent your pies, you should be able to determine the difference by the color you see through the vent for fruit pies with two crusts.  You can make some very pretty pies with large vents that look quite attractive.  Even pies with a crumble or crisp topping should show a bit of their fillings in parts.

Answer (score 4):

As with everything you put in the refrigerator and freezer, label and date it.

Comment: Agreed on the date -- and I've even gotten into the habit on some dishes of listing ingredients (was helpful for the meals I gave my sister-in-law when she was pregnant, as she started having issues with some things, so could tell what stuff to save 'til later)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a two-crust pie, you should be able to flip it over, and cut a small hole in the center, take out a core sample, and examine the interior.

Flipping them over is also one of the best ways of cutting many pies, since it will cause less damage to the sides, and thus a more visually appealing slice.